# shell script to check uploaded pdf is malicious or not without antivirus

Tags: shell, pdf

Is there any way to check uploaded pdf is malicious or not without ClamAV or any other antivirus, and I need to verify it using linux shell script. I have tried with peepdf or pdfid, however could not make it work.

Comment: Are you asking for another 3rd party tool? If so, that's off-topic. Otherwise... I can't really tell what you're asking for help with. Also: You don't need to tell people to help - I removed that from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

Peepdf is great, assuming you have pylibemu and PyV8 installed. Even then it seems you need to be quite knowledgeable about (generally) how to interpret the results and (specifically) javascript, which seems to be the chief antagonist in a malicious pdf file.

The answer to your question is to set about writing a script yourself (using gawk, python, perl perhaps?) which will parse the results according to your own pre-established criteria.

And I assume you meant downloaded, as opposed to uploaded pdfs?